# How to extract this .tgz file in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, extract

I have install cygwin and want to install a tgz file. I typed following command:

```
$tar xvfz tidy_src.tgz
```

Error occurs:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then I type following command to check;
    $file tidy_src.tgz
It shows it's a ASCII text
So I continue type:

```
$tar xvf tidy_src.tgz
```

Still doesn't work.

Anyone can give some help?

You can download this free-virus file at http://tidy.sourceforge.net/src/tidy_src.tgz

Comment: Your arhive seems to be damaged or currupted. Can't open it either.
Has a size of 9 bytes, something is wrong with it.

Comment: It is 1k. Can you tell me if I am extracting it correctly?

Comment: Windows may say in details view that is 1kb, but check file properties, i has 9bytes with this text: "Use CVS.". That is not an archive, is a plain text file with .tgz extension.

Answer (score 0):

untarring a gzipped file that you have made yourself from known content with the same command.

if that works then you confirm that the archive is corrupt.